# Perchance and Mayhap

Tags: british-english, early-modern-english, seventeenth-century-english

I'm writing a screenplay set in England 17th century 1608. Which was more common "Mayhap" or "Perchance". The meaning is "maybe". Ex: Perchance/Mayhap we will live a long life.

Comment: Check out https://books.google.com/ngrams/ which lets you see the frequency of words in books scanned by Google. You can enter "mayhap, perchance" into the search field and control the time period you are interested in.

Comment: Here's my advice: Go to the Searchable Shakespeare. See perchance: https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/search/search-results.php No mayhap at all. So maybe stay away from it? :) Anyway, a good source for you.

Comment: The King James Bible doesn't seem to have either (but it's not exactly conversational English) https://thekingsbible.com/Concordance/mayhap

Comment: I'd say the positioning matters.'They will perchance ...' has probably always been far less uncommon than 'They will mayhap ...'.

Comment: The OED's first citation for ***mayhap*** is several decades after Shakespeare was born (and identified as "dialectal"), but they have ***perchance*** from at least a couple of centuries earlier (and it sits alongside everyday ***perhaps*** and "literary" ***peradventure***). A pretty clear difference, so it all depends on your context.

Comment: Be careful. There's nothing quite so annoying as fake 'Olde Englisshe' dialog full of prithees, gadzookses, mayhaps, etc. If you aren't an expert in this kind of thing (and you wouldn't be here if you were), I suggest you find another project. Although I daresay there are some markets where it will be OK. (No names, no pack-drill, eh, @FumbleFingers?)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Quite. It's no biggie if someone gets "medieval idiomacy" wrong when they're being *facetious.* But if you've got even a nodding acquaintance with our literary history, you'll probably at least *notice* the (typesetting?) error in ... [*Once the number three, being the third number, be reached, then lobbest thou thy Holy Hand Grenade of Antioch towards thou foe, who being naughty in my sight, shall snuff it.](https://www.pastemagazine.com/movies/monty-python/monty-python-and-the-holy-grail-best-quotes)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - yes, I _noticed_ it.

Comment: I easily spotted it too. Just glancing through a few "best mock olde english gags" looking for a suitable candidate. I don't have easy access to *Monty Python and the Holy Grail,* but checking an actual movie subtitle I see they've got it right there. Point being - if you get it wrong, it can be *really* noticeable! (Like "non-idiomatic" swearing! :)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Actually, I just read that gag again from the beginning (for the laff! :). There's another mistake I didn't notice first time around: *Three shalt be the number thou shalt count, and the number of the counting shalt be three.* Probably missed it because I was distracted laughing. But *again* I see it's correct in the actual subtitle *...the number of the counting **shall** be three).* Whatever happened to "cut and paste"? I think the *first* "shalt" cited there is a *deliberate* mistake by the Pythons themselves.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - the Pythons were considerable scholars. Terry Jones published a number of books of mediaeval history. I think it's quite possible that they knew what they were doing. It is a cheerful send-up. _Dennis the Mud Farmer: Strange women layin' in ponds distributin' swords is no basis for a system of government!_